# Viewing xml data in Linux?

Tags: xml, linux, openstreetmap, fedora

I know variations of this question have been asked but I'm still trying to find the best answer. I have xml file which is about 470 MB and I'd like to navigate through it to see what the data looks like because I need to run a program over this data. But I'm not able to move ahead since the file is so large and Gedit is not a good choice obviously. (linux beginner)

Secondly, a major problem is that that data that I want to look at is after about 500000 lines so I cannot use something like "less" since it works line by line (?) Again I'm a beginner but eager to learn and I'm coding Python over Openstreetmap data. So yeah, please help! :)

Comment: @user165971 have you tried opening the file in a terminal text editor, like vim?

Comment: If it is OSM XML (which I guess from the tagging) you can download a smaller xml when clicking e.g. on 'export' of the official osm.org page. Do that for a smaller area and you can open it in a browser and learn about it and start coding how to parse it, especially when you create unit tests you should do so for a smaller xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the terminal and the commands to extract partial data:
* head
* tail
* grep

You can also rediret the output to a new file and so create an smal extract.

BTW: The OSM XML format is specified over here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML